# Date format in PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am learning PHP, and have a piece of PHP code that queries a Database. I obtain a date that is already in the Database and was wondering whether this piece of code `format('dd-mm-yyyy');` would work to format the data from the default 'YYYY-MM-DD' to 'DD-MM-YYYY' and how the code can be utilsed?

```
<?php 

    $rfp = $_GET['cid'];
 // Connects to Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT rfp_id, issue_date, rfp_status.status FROM company, rfp, rfp_status WHERE company.company_id = rfp.company_id AND rfp_status.status_id = rfp.status_id AND company.company_id = '$rfp'") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
  echo "<table border=1px cellpadding=15 bordercolor='#0000CC'>";
   #echo "<table border=0 cellpadding=15 bordercolor='#0000CC'>";
echo "<tr align = center bgcolor=white>
<td><b>RFP ID</b></td><td><b>Date Added</b></td><td><b>Status</b></td>" ; 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
      $rid = $row['rfp_id'];  
      $idate = $row['issue_date'];
      $status = $row['status'];

# inserts value into table as a hyperlink

echo "<tr align = center bgcolor=white><td>$rid</td><td><b><a target='_blank' href=view_section_detail.php?rid=$rid>$idate</a></b></td><td>$status</td>";
}

# displays table

print '</table>';

 ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, please don't learn the deprecated `mysql_query` interface. It's in the process of being phased out of PHP in favor of the newer `mysqli` and PDO interfaces which are a lot safer to use. In your short example here you have a **severe** [SQL injection vulnerability](http://bobby-tables.com/php), `$rfp` is not properly escaped, that wouldn't happen when using the newer interfaces and SQL placeholders. It's worth the small amount of time it takes to switch to the current interfaces rather than create a brand new legacy application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it directly in the database query like this using mysql [date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT rfp_id, date_format(issue_date,'%d-%m-%Y') as issue_date... etc
```

Comment: what if `issue_date` isn't date ?

Comment: @MihaiIorga I took a punt on the column name - figured it was the most likely candidate to be the date field.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, you can use **[`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(colName, '%d-%m-%Y') formattedDate
FROM...
WHERE ...
```

**[Other Formats here](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)**

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/2056)

Answer (score 2):

There is no `format()`:

```
$idate = strtotime($row['issue_date']); // assuming $row['issue_date'] is YYYY-MM-DD
$idate = date('d-m-Y', $idate);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$idate = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row['issue_date']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
      $rid = $row['rfp_id'];  
      $idate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['issue_date']));
      $status = $row['status'];

# inserts value into table as a hyperlink

echo "<tr align = center bgcolor=white><td>$rid</td><td><b><a target='_blank' href=view_section_detail.php?rid=$rid>$idate</a></b></td><td>$status</td>";
}
```