# Issue in SQL Server with updating date records

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

So i have this query which outputs me some data.

I have this query here:

```
$lista="Select * from forma WHERE id=$id" or die(odbc_error());
```

forma table has a data column, which is of datetime type , and i need it to print like:
Y/m/d type.

How can i do this please? In the query?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date format in PHP/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461299/date-format-in-php-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`CONVERT`**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)  of SQL Server.

See

```
Select convert(varchar(10),yourdatefield,1) AS '[YOUR FORMAT]' from table name
```

Read this:

- [**How to format a Date or DateTime in SQL Server**.](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/13/format-date-sql-server.aspx)

Comment: YES, But i don't understand that!
Could you please see this from my query?